# don't have permission to access / on this server. but i can access phpmyadmin

Tags: php, permissions, localhost, wampserver

i'm biginner with wamp, i have windows 7, apache 2.4.9 .

Whene i try  `"http://localhost"` I get the "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

i have no probleme with `"http://localhost/phpmyadmin"`.

this is a part of my httpd.conf may help :

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all         
</Directory>
```

and this my phpmyadmin.conf :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1

    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

What should I do ?

Comment: What else have you changed in your httpd.conf file? Also why are you using Apache 2.2 syntax on an Apache 2.4 installation i.e. `Allow from` should be `Require`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all         
</Directory>
```

Should be returned to its original state

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

This controls access to the drive that Apache is installed on i.e. `C:\`. If you set this to allow access then you are making your whole C:\ drive potentially accessible to anybody.

Its not to big an issue while you are using WAMPServer as a development tool, but if you decide to make a site available for some remote testing and you open up your router then **WAMMO Hackers paradise**.

Answer (score 0):

Try followin [this](http://www.hieule.info/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8/) guide. This should help you out.

In basics, you have to allow your own PC:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: [Link only answers are not good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Links can break at any time. At least add the relevant bit of content from the linked page...

Answer (score 0):

General ip permisson (working tested):

```
  <Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
      <IfDefine APACHE24>
        #Require local
        Require ip 192.168.0
      </IfDefine>
      <IfDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
          Deny from all
          #Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
          Allow from 192.168.0
        </IfDefine>
      php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
      php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
      php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
      php_admin_value max_input_time 360
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
//EDIT: removed the arguments for path in <Directory> tag.

<Directory />
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Not entirely sure I am also fairly new to this stuff..

Hope it helps!

Comment: Use this ONLY IF you want to expose your whole `C:\` drive to be accessible from the internet. **In other words DONT DO THIS**